# Differences between Dixit versions?

Tags: dixit

I'm concerned my niece, who's ten and has been raised on the likes of Hannah Montana, has little to no imagination or creativity. I want to find games we can play that will push her thinking out of the Disney drone-mold and I think that Dixit looks perfect for this. However, there's a problem; there are too many versions.

Amazon.co.uk stocks the following versions of Dixit:

- [Dixit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asmodee-Editions-5511302-Dixit-Board/dp/B001OH9EDW/ref=pd_bxgy_k_h_b_cs_img_y)
- [Dixit 2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asmodee-Dix02-Dixit-2/dp/B0037LXTUW/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1374751474&sr=8-2&keywords=dixit)
- [Dixit 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Libellud-001601-Dixit-3/dp/B008YDC454/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1374751474&sr=8-5&keywords=dixit)
- [Dixit Odyssey](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asmodee-ASMDIX03-Dixit-Odyssey-Game/dp/B004WRJ382/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1374751474&sr=8-3&keywords=dixit)
- [Dixit Journey](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dixit-Journey-Board-Game-DIX04ASM/dp/B007PJFIU6/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1374751474&sr=8-4&keywords=dixit)

To me Odyssey looks the most random, but may be too far out for someone with little imagination, at least to start with. Common sense suggests starting with Dixit, as it's the first, but that also makes it the oldest; theoretically the newest would be the most stable and well made.

I'm not looking for opinions here, rather I'm after facts about the different games that may help decide which one is right for us.

So my question is: What makes each version of Dixit different, and what can you tell me about each that may help decide which version is best for my situation?

Comment: Why did you rollback the title revision? Do you disagree that it's more accurate?

Comment: I removed the recommendations tag because this tag is deprecated and should not be used. The tag is an unhelpful meta tag, and in general recommendation questions are not allowed. See http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-we-ban-game-recommendation-questions-done for more information.

Comment: Sorry @ire_and_curses, didn't dissagree, was only trying to revert my formatting, I only dissagreed with the correction of my use of semi colons. And fair enough, like I said; I didn't add it myself, is it possible to get it removed from the lookup?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I personally own all of the above apart from Dixit Journey (which I didn't even know existed).

You should know that, Dixit 2 and 3, aren't technically stand-alone games; they're only sets of additional cards.

Dixit Oddysey is nearly the same as original Dixit when it comes to rules. As far as I remember it has all the rules the original had, plus some additions for bigger number of players. It also has a set of pieces for greater number of players (up to 12, I think). The biggest difference are the actual cards - those are entirely new when compared to original.

My recommendation is to buy the Oddysey, as it contains the game pieces helpful* in playing a game and a manual. Then if your niece likes the game you could buy the others for additional cards.

*) As long as you have access to the game rules, you don't really need anything apart from the cards. All the other pieces in the boxes are used to keep track of players score, and to 'vote' for the cards - if you can manage this some other way (easiest and most crude would be pen&paper solution) you could buy only the cards.

Comment: One important change in the rules between 'core' Dixit and Odyssey is that point values for a couple of events (most notably, offering up a card that nobody guesses correctly) have changed to be a bit less penalizing.  Also, while this is sort of noted in passing, the 'mechanisms' for handling guessing - that is, the chits used for voting - also seem a bit better in Odyssey than they were in the base set.

Comment: What's the difference between just additional cards, and a stand-alone game for Dixit?

Comment: @GendoIkari You may think of the cards as expansion to the game. The cards come in small boxes, containing nothing else besides them - no rules, no board to track points, no chips for voting. All of these are present in the main editions of the game (e.g. Dixit Oddysey). As I mentioned in my answer, as long as you know the rules, and can somehow arrange for keeping score and voting, you don't really need nothing more than cards.

Answer (score 9):

The concept of all the Dixit games are the same, they just have different images. The regular Dixit's images are definitely random. The Odyssey and Journey are more themed around travel and adventure. If you are a fantasy adventure person, I'd recommend Journey because there is Harry potter and Lord of the Rings references galore to be made. As for the regular Dixits (1,2, and 3) they all will be of the same quality of playing so if you have the chance to look at the cards, pick the pack with your favorite artwork. The whole point of the game is to see the creative things people see in each card. You and your niece may not think of the same idea for one card and that is the beauty and re-usability of the game.

Comment: Thank you @juleekwin; I've selected ykb's answer due to its specificity, but this has been very helpful

Answer (score 4):

We bought the Journey version for our 8 year old a couple of years ago. We liked the concept of the game, but the images used in this version are dark and a bit disturbing. Almost all of them depict sad or angry characters in depressing or distressed scenes. I do not recommend this version as a family-friendly game.

Comment: Thanks Kristin, facts like this make it much easier to choose :)

Answer (score 1):

old thread, but I stumbled upon it when googling, so I'm sure others will to.
There's a good comparison of all the dixit products here:
https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/171700/dixit-product-guide

Comment: Try to avoid link-only answers because the linked site might go down at some point. Instead, summarize the information in your answer and post a link to your source.

Answer (score 0):

the journey is a complete set with all of the board, pieces, and rules, but if she is more Disney then abstract the pictures on this may just be a little more freighting then fun.